# How to merge multple XML files and make proper namespaces in result XML

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have few XMLs needs to be merged and create a new xml. How i can extract the xml namespaces from the xmls and use it for resulting xml.

xml1

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <root1 xmlns:xlink="ABC/xlink" xmlns:xsi="XYZ/instance">
 <tag1>123</tag1>
 </root1>
```

xml2

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <root2 xmlns:xlink2="EFG/xlink2" xmlns:xsi="XYZ/instance">
 <tag2>321</tag2>
 </root2>
```

expected result xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <root xmlns:xlink="ABC/xlink" xmlns:xsi="XYZ/instance" xmlns:xlink2="EFG/xlink2">
 <tag1>123</tag1>
 <tag2>321</tag2>
 </root>
```

Currently i am trying like below

```
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("xmlns[\\s\\S]*?>");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringxml);
      while(matcher.find()){
       //storing the namespace.
      }
```

Trying to do String manipulation to create the proper xml namespace. There are quite a few string operations happening to handle the namespace properly like need to avoid the duplicate namespace if its defined in both xmls. Is there any other better way to do it ?

Comment: I haven't touched XML for a while.  Are you sure your XML are valid?  Is the expected output XML correct?

Comment: yes XMLs are valid and expected result xml also valid.

Comment: There are APIs and languages to process and transform and change or merge XML, Java has strong support for XSLT 1 built-in and has open-source solutions with Saxon for XSLT 3.0 and XQuery 3.1 and with BaseX or exist-db for XQuery 3.1. There are also various APIs like JDOM, XOM. So there is certainly no need for string operations based on regular expressions. Of course that simple example doesn't explain your merging requirement but dealing with namespaces is certainly not something you need regular expressions for.